# Set up a conference call in Twilio with a bidrectional stream (python)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Currently, I am trying to a create a conference call between 3 people: a moderator, a recipient, and a bot. The bot should communicate with the conference call by setting up a <Stream> to get audio from the recipient and respond back. The moderator should just listen in but can kick the bot out at of the conference at any point in time. I am trying the following, but can't seem to get it working properly. What is the correct way to do this:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
twilio_client = Client(twilio_config.account_sid, twilio_config.auth_token)

moderator_call = self.twilio_client.calls.create(
url=f"https://{self.base_url}/twiml/conference_moderator/{self.conversation_id}",
to=mod_phone,
from_=bot_phone,
record=record,
)

recipient_call = self.twilio_client.calls.create(
url=f"https://{self.base_url}/twiml/conference_recipient/{self.conversation_id}",
to=to_phone,
from_=bot_phone,
record=record,
)
```

```
self.router.add_api_route(
"/twiml/conference_recipient/{id}",
self.call_conference_recipient,
methods=["POST"],
)
self.router.add_api_route(
"/twiml/conference_moderator/{id}", self.call_conference_mod, methods=["POST"]
)
```

```
def call_conference_recipient(self, id: str):
  response = VoiceResponse()
  start = Connect()
  start.stream(url=f"wss://{self.base_url}/connect_call/{id}")
  response.append(start)
  with response.dial() as dial:
    dial.conference(id, start_conference_on_enter=True)
  return Response(str(response), media_type="application/xml")

def call_conference_mod(self, id: str):
  response = VoiceResponse()
  with response.dial() as dial:
    dial.conference(id, start_conference_on_enter=False)
  return Response(str(response), media_type="application/xml")
```

Is there any way to setup a stream in a conference call, or way to get around this?

see description for more details